# Find and replace a number using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of HTML that gets repeated over and over using jQuery (when a user clicks 'add' it creates another block:

```
<p>
<label for="question[1][text]">Question: <span class="req">*</span></label>
<input name="question[1][text]" id="A_Question_1" value="" type="text" class="f_input" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="question[1][type]">Type: <span class="req">*</span></label>
<input name="question[1][type]" id="A_Type_1" type="text" class="f_input" />
</p>
```

I need to increment each number by 1 for each iteration of that block, so that the next block automatically creates:

```
<p>
<label for="question[2][text]">Question: <span class="req">*</span></label>
<input name="question[2][text]" id="A_Question_1" value="" type="text" class="f_input" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="question[2][type]">Type: <span class="req">*</span></label>
<input name="question[2][type]" id="A_Type_1" type="text" class="f_input" />
</p>
```

I'm sure it's simple enough but I'm not experienced enough with Regexs etc. to work out how to go about it. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you mean to increment the `id` attributes as well? E.g. `id="A_Question_1"` to `id="A_Question_2"`.

Answer (score 2):

[JQote](http://aefxx.com/api/jqote2-reference/) offers an HTML templating library for JQuery. It is invoked with an object containing its parameters.

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
<![CDATA[
    <p>
        <label for="question[<%= this.iteration %>][text]">Question: <span class="req">*</span></label>
        <input name="question[<%= this.iteration %>][text]" id="A_Question_<%= this.iteration %>" value="" type="text" class="f_input" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="question[<%= this.iteration %>][type]">Type: <span class="req">*</span></label>
        <input name="question[<%= this.iteration %>][type]" id="A_Type_<%= this.iteration %>" type="text" class="f_input" />
    </p>
]]>
</script>
```

Then as part of your `add()` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var globalIteration = 0

    function add() {

      <...your code...> 

      globalIteration++;
      var obj= {
        iteration: globalIteration,
        <...any other variables to insert into template...>
      };  
      $('#template').jqote(obj).appendTo($('body'));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store template in some hidden div with placeholders for ids (something like `#id#`).
Then, you can replace placeholders with actual id in javascript. Something like

```
var html = $('#template').html().replace('#id#', id);
list.append(html);
```

The next id can be calculated from the current amount of children.

```
var id = list.children().length + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $container = $('#container');
  $button = $('#button')
  .data('clicked', 0)
  .click(function() {
    var clicked = $button.data('clicked');
    $container.append('<p><label for="question[' + clicked + '][text]">Question: <span class="req">*</span></label><input name="question[' + clicked + '][text]" id="A_Question_' + clicked + '" value="" type="text" class="f_input" /></p>');
    $button.data('clicked', clicked + 1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are binding your function. If you are binding it in javascript I would probably use the number as a fake property of the add link.

Something like

```
'<a href="javascript:;" question_number="1">Add</a>
```

Replace [1] with $(this).attr('question_number') in your javascript and at the end add $(this).attr('question_number', nextId)

A better solution might be to tack it on to the id of the link and change the id when the javascript finishes, not a good solution if you are binding by id though.

If you are binding the onclick directly in the html using something like

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="my_func();">Add</a/>
```

modify your function to take a parameter and change the paramter at the end of the javascript similar to above. I also like Andy's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have done it http://pintum.com.au/goCruising/details.html#tabs-2
Click the add button.

It uses  jQuery, jtemplates plugin and JSON.  Just look at the source for how it works.